# Forming a variable name with string + integer and calling functions

Tags: delphi

Firstly, I am new to these and the question could be stupid. Anyway, I have a procedure like this:

```
procedure Tform1.QueryChange(sqltext : String; query : Integer);
begin
if query = 1 then begin
ADOQuery1.Close;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add(sqltext);
ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
if query = 2 then begin
ADOQuery2.Close;
ADOQuery2.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery2.SQL.Add(sqltext);
ADOQuery2.Open;
end;
```

I would like to remove the if blocks and make one united code:

```
ADOQuery+query.Close; (know that looks very silly)
ADOQuery+query.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery+query.SQL.Add(sqltext);
ADOQuery+query.Open;
```

My goal is when query=1 code will use ADOQuery1.Close; etc.
when query=2 code will use ADOQuery2.Close;

Comment: only from curiosity , why not QueryChange(const sqltext : String; query : TAdoQuery); ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of creating variables `ADOQuery1`, `ADOQuery2`, `ADOQuery3` etc of type `TADOQuery`, create an array:

```
ADOQueries: array of TADOQuery;
```

Then set the number of elements in it, when you know how many they will be:

```
SetLength(ADOQueries, NumberOfQueries);
```

Alternatively, if you know from the beginning how many elements there will be, you can define `ADOQueries` to be a static array instead:

```
ADOQueries: array[0..7] of TADOQuery;
```

Now you can do

```
procedure TForm1.QueryChange(sqltext: String; query: Integer);
begin
  ADOQueries[Query].Close;
  ADOQueries[Query].SQL.Clear;
  ADOQueries[Query].SQL.Add(sqltext);
  ADOQueries[Query].Open;
end;
```

Comment: If you want to talk about elegance, I'd draw attention to the repeated lookup of the array. I'd declare a local variable `Query: TADOQuery` and at the start of the method write `Query := ADOQueries[Query]`. Use `Query` from then on. That has the benefit that you do not repeat yourself.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. This was what I want. Now, I would like to check that if a particular query is already created or not. something like if (adoqueries[query] is not created) then create...

Comment: @user1899291 what you want is `if ADOQueries[query] = nil then ADOQueries[query] := TADOQuery.Create(nil);`.

Comment: If you call `SetLength` on an array, don't forget to later call `SetLength(ADOQueries, 0)` to free the array memory.

Comment: @DavidM No need, that happens when the array leaves scope

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't know that.  You don't need to manually free the array?  Is this for local methods only, or for class fields too?

Comment: @David M: Arrays are always freed automatically when they go out of scope, as are integers, strings, booleans, records, etc. But if your array consists of objects, then these objects will not be freed automatically. Only the array is freed, but this is only an array of pointers (i.e., intetgers).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: thanks.  Does that include object members - ie, if I have a dynamic array as a field in TMyClass, and later call InstanceOfMyClass.Free, will that free the array too?

Answer (score 8):

You could create a local variable that referred to the `TADOQuery` object that you wish to operate on. Like this:

```
var
  ADOQuery: TADOQuery;
begin
  if query=1 then
    ADOQuery := ADOQuery1
  else if query=2 then
    ADOQuery := ADOQuery2;
  ADOQuery.Close;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery.SQL.Add(sqltext);
  ADOQuery.Open;      
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can do this is with the [FindComponent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) method, ie assuming the form owns the query components

```
procedure Tform1.QueryChange(sqltext : String; query : Integer);
var cmp: TComponent;
    Query: TADOQuery;
begin
  cmp := FindComponent('ADOQuery' + IntToStr(query));
  if cmp <> nil then begin
     Query := cmp as TADOQuery;
     Query.Close;
     ...
  end;  
end;
```

Comment: But this is much less elegant than David's and my solutions. However, since there might be some academical interest in listing different solutions, I will not downvote.

Comment: I can't imagine doing it this way, but I'll upvote all the same. It's a perfectly reasonable answer. Normally you'd not want TADOQuery objects as published components on .dfm files and instead create them programmatically. But for a component that did naturally live in the .dfm file this is a sane way to do it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree that you don't want these components on a form, and would create them in code my self, but in the drag-n-drop way of developing their natural habitat would be a data module and data modules are streamed just like forms are. So, if you are already using data modules, ain's solution would be a good way of doing it.