# Calling Objects by number

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I have 8 labels named Labelf1, Labelf2 and so on. Now inside a while do loop, that counts from 1 to 8 I want to assign a Caption to the label corresponding to the number the loop is at. 
E.g.: the counting variable is i, then I would need to do something like `Labelf<i>.Caption := String`.

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: Add the labels to an array. Btw this question is asked at least once a month if not more frequently. Try some web search.

Comment: I did not even consider Arrays as a solution. Thanks :). As to the research, I tried searching for a solution but didn't find anything. Maybe i just had the wrong keywords.

Comment: [How can I refer to a control whose name is determined at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13649250/593144), [Use variables for object name in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18812960/593144) and so on...