# Insert existing TLabels into a dynamically created array of TLabels

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to create a dynamic array of `TLabel`s, then insert already existing `TLabel`s created in the IDE into it so I can then use the array in the code.

My purpose is to use this method for several similar processes.

I would like to make it by using loops.

I saw this thread and it was very helpful to understand about creating arrays of `TLabel`s and populating them with `TLabel`s for the desired purposes, but I couldnt find the particular solution for the case when the labels are already created.

[Use variables for object name in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812960/)

Basically, what I'm trying to automate is this:

```
var 
  LabelArray : array of TLabel;

SetLength(LabelArray, 17);

LabelArray[0] := M2;
LabelArray[1] := M3;
            .
            .
LabelArray[16] := M18
```

`M2` to `M18` are 17 labels that are the `TLabel`s already created and positioned on the Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the form's `FindComponent` method to add the labels to your array.

The code below depends on your having declared `LabelArray` as a private variable at the form level, so that it exists and is visible when the form is created and the code executes. It also hard-codes in 17 as the number of labels, so if you delete or rename a label you'll have an empty spot in the array - I did not include any error checking to make sure a label is found before putting it into the array and the element could end up `nil` if a label is missing.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(LabelArray, 17);
  { 
    I use Low() and High() here to avoid having multiple places where
    you would have to change the code if you end up adding or removing 
    labels in the future.

    Also note that the index into the array starts at 0, so the code that
    calls Format() adjusts that index by 2 to start at M2 instead of M0.
  }
  for i := Low(LabelArray) to High(LabelArray) do
    LabelArray[i] := TLabel(FindComponent(Format('M%d', [i + 2])));
end;
```

Comment: Ive already tried it and tested it doesnt sends error at executing the code, but as i try to use the Tlabel array Tlabel names it triggers acces violation for read adress. I guess theres something causing it because it cannot acces to the list of the array created.

Comment: @Supergomes: Then you've not provided the accurate information about your labels, because my code is correct if you've got the situation you described. Your labels are named differently, or you've not used the code I've posted. I can assure you that the code I posted works, because I've used code very similar to it for years.

Comment: Maybe is related to the labels, as im refering to Tlabel names as Tlabel.name property.

Comment: @Supergomes: My code uses the names you said you gave your labels (`M2` through `M18`). As I said, it works with the information you've provided.

Comment: your solution worked, i don't know if i was doing something wrong but the solution as it was wrote by you sent me read error, i looked around for formating styles till one format didnt send me error. the format for the line was like this one: LabelArray[i] := TLabel(Findcomponent(Format(String('%s'),['M'+inttostr(i+2)+'']))); Thank you for your support. :)

Comment: Your format statement makes no sense. My apologies, though - mine had a typo. Use it as it is now instead. If you want to do it your way instead, change your code to `TLabel(FindComponent('M' + IntToStr(i + 2)));` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your labels cannot be found using a common name scheme, but you simply want to get all labels on the same panel / group box etc. into the array, you can use the Controls[] property of the parent control:

```
SetLength(LabelArray, ParentCtrl.ControlCount);
cnt := 0;
for i := 0 to ParentCtrl.ControlCount - 1 do begin
  if ParentCtrl.Controls[i] is TLabel then begin
    LabelArray[cnt] := TLabel(ParentCtrl.Controls[i]);
    Inc(cnt);
  end;
end;
SetLength(LabelArray, cnt);
```

ParentCtrl is the panel / groupbox or even the form itself that is the common parent of all the labels you are interested in.

If you simply want all labels on a form, even if they are located on other controls, you can use the Components[] property of the form in the same way.